# Rename all files

Tags: shell-script, rhel, rename

I have 800 file with naming as:

```
Centrum.text.201601-01
Centrum.text.201601-02
```

till 30 for a month 01 and so on for all the 12 months .

I want is to rename all the files in a single go as:

```
Centrum.201601-01.text
Centrum.201602-12.text
```

and so on for the corresponding months.

A one-liner if possible.
Os -- rhel5

Comment: How do the first two file names correspond to the second two? Which part of the filename needs to be transcribed to the target? Is it `Centrum.text.YYYYMM-DD` mapped to `Centrum.YYYYDD-MM.text`, for example? Or `Centrum.text.XXXXXX-XX` mapped to `Centrum.XXXXXX-XX.text` (i.e. just moving the `text` part)? Please [edit] your question to make it clear.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
 rename -n 's/Centrum.text.(.*)/Centrum.$1.text/' Cen*
```

for a preview

- `s/Centrum.text.(.*)/Centrum.$1.text/` instruct to replace (moving en pattern inside)

then

```
rename  's/Centrum.text.(.*)/Centrum.$1.text/' Cen*
```

Edit:

if you don't have rename, and from directory containing files

```
ls -1 | awk -F. '/Centrum/ {printf "mv %s.%s.%s %s.%s.%s\n",$1,$2,$3,$1,$3,$2}'
```

for the preview

- `-1` (one file per line) in `ls` might be useless, but just in case you have alias to ls.
- `/Centrum/` filter on filename
- `{printf "mv %s.%s.%s %s.%s.%s\n",$1,$2,$3,$1,$3,$2}` swap date and text field.

add `| bash` at the end if all is good.

Comment: Note that this will only work if the OP has `rename` pointing to Perl `rename` which is the default on Debian based systems.

Comment: @archemar: nothing happens. These files are inside a directory named avi

Comment: @ABHISHEKSHARMA if the files are in a subdirectory, and you didn't tell us that, you need to be in that subdirectory to apply the command.

Comment: @don_crissti you are absolutly right, can you point me to rename's for HP-UX and Solaris ? (question was tag rhel after my first answer), besides I like overly obfuscate code. :)

Comment: @don_crissti rightly or wrongly, I wasn't responding to the merits (or otherwise) of the answer. I was concerned that the "_nothing happens_" coupled with "_These files are inside a directory named `avi`_" might mean that the OP had simply run the command without thinking about the context.

Comment: I tagged it RHEL based on the tail of the question, "_Os -- rhel5_"

Comment: @don_crissti yes. I worked on these plateforms ere linux was born, so I kept my bad habits. (in fact I discover `rename` on U&L SE)

Comment: @Archemar - ok, thanks for taking the time to reply. I'll delete my comments here but I'm just curious as I've never had the opportunity to work on HPUX: isn't shell parameter expansion available ? e.g. on  any POSIX compliant shell you can simply do `for f in Cen*; do mv "$f" Centrum."${f##*.}".text; done`